# List item dipping too low in IE8 and upwards

Tags: css, internet-explorer, position

I have a simple navigation bar which was creating using list items. For some reason, the final list item is dipping below the rest of them and I can't figure out why.

You can see it happening here if you view in IE: http://www.thatcreative.co.uk/staging/

As far as I can tell this happens in all versions of IE except for 6.

I could not find any other questions which covered this issue.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like a margin problem, you have list's left margin set at 34px. Try reducing it for the last item. It did the trick for me. I set the margin for 4px, and it came back up.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure how I overlooked that one!